# Get nearest sequence result from an array and given pattern with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, compare, sequence, string-comparison

I am trying to get year and month from the letters using established sequence. I know that the sequence is based on the following letters:

```
$letters = array('B','C','D','F','G','H','J','K','L','M','N','P','R','S','T','V','W','X','Y','Z');
```

It started with 0000BBB and when it reaches 9999 it becomes BBC, BBD etc. So I don't need the numbers in that case and only letters as I have a list of last registered sequence per year and month like this:

```
$plates = array(
            array('2018','KHF','KHX','KJV','KKN','KLM','KML','KNK','KPD','KPR','KPT','----','----'),
            array('2017','JWN','JXF','JYB','JYT','JZP','KBM','KCH','KCV','KDK','KFB','KFV','KGN'),
            array('2016','JLN','JMF','JMY','JNR','JPK','JRG','JRZ','JSL','JTB','JTR','JVH','JVZ'),
            array('2015','JCK','JCY','JDR','JFG','JFW','JGP','JHJ','JHT','JJH','JJW','JKK','JKZ'),
            array('2014','HVN','HVZ','HWM','HXB','HXN','HYD','HTY','HZB','HZL','HZZ','JBL','JBY'),
            array('2013','HNT','HPC','HPN','HPY','HRK','HRX','HSK','HSR','HSZ','HTK','HTV','HVF'),
            array('2012','HJC','HJM','HKB','HKL','HKX','HLK','HLW','HMD','HML','HMT','HNC','HNK'),
            array('2011','HBP','HCB','HCR','HDC','HDR','HFF','HFT','HGC','HGM','HGX','HHH','HHT'),
            array('2010','GTC','GTS','GVM','GWC','GWV','GXP','GYD','GYM','GYX','GZJ','GZT','HBG'),
            array('2009','GKS','GLC','GLP','GMC','GMN','GNF','GNY','GPJ','GPW','GRM','GSC','GSR'),
            array('2008','FZR','GBN','GCK','GDH','GFC','GFY','GGV','GHG','GHT','GJJ','GJV','GKH'),
            array('2007','FKY','FLV','FNB','FNZ','FRC','FSJ','FTP','FVJ','FWC','FXB','FXY','FYY'),
            array('2006','DVW','DWT','DXZ','DYY','FBC','FCJ','FDP','FFK','FGF','FHD','FJD','FKC'),
            array('2005','DFZ','DGX','DHZ','DKB','DLD','DMJ','DNP','DPK','DRG','DSC','DTB','DVB'),
            array('2004','CRV','CSS','CTT','CVR','CWR','CXT','CYY','CZP','DBJ','DCH','DDG','DFF'),
            array('2003','CDV','CFM','CGJ','CHF','CJC','CKB','CLD','CLV','CMM','CNK','CPF','CRC'),
            array('2002','BSL','BTF','BTZ','BVW','BWT','BXP','BYP','BZF','BZV','CBP','CCH','CDC'),
            array('2001','BFJ','BGF','BHG','BJC','BKB','BLC','BMF','BMW','BNL','BPG','BRB','BRT'),
            array('2000','---','---','---','---','---','---','---','---','BBJ','BCD','BCY','BDR')
        );
```

That means that array index 0 is the year and from 1 to 12 would be month. I am trying to find a match but then realize I can not search exact value and need to look for nearest value based on letters.

**I would deeply appreciate if anyone could direct me in right direction what would be the best method of doing this.**

This is a test so far but this will just return an exact match, I would have to search any possible letters such as **KHW** as an example that would have to match as nearest value to **KHX**

```
foreach ($plates as $key => $val) {                        
            $search = array_search('KHX', $plates[$key]);            
            if($search){
                echo $search."\n";
                echo $plates[$key][0];
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Now I get it.. I think.. If I search for FNA I would get result of FNB? If I search for BHI I would get a result of BHG? And if I search for CGJ I would get CGJ because it already exists?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld yes (except that A, nor I are used in allowed letters) but it is quite chalenging as it must be the nearest to possible sequence as the array contains only last registered sequences of the month meaning we can not search only by first or first two letters. The sequence started at BBB and will end at ZZZ. E.g: BBC BBD ... BBZ and then we proceed to BCB BCC BCD etc.

Comment: So If I understand this right. If you search for BTG you get the result because BTF is closer then BTZ?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it with O(log n) with a binary search. But in a more straightforward solution, you can solve it with O(n).
You can calculate the difference between each word with the below algorithm.
‍‍

```
<?php

function strToInt($str)
{
    $result = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        $result = $result * 100 + ord($str[$i]);
    }

    return $result;
}

function find($searchStr)
{
    $plates = [
        ['2018','KHF','KHX','KJV','KKN','KLM','KML','KNK','KPD','KPR','KPT','----','----'],
        ['2017','JWN','JXF','JYB','JYT','JZP','KBM','KCH','KCV','KDK','KFB','KFV','KGN'],
        ['2016','JLN','JMF','JMY','JNR','JPK','JRG','JRZ','JSL','JTB','JTR','JVH','JVZ'],
        ['2015','JCK','JCY','JDR','JFG','JFW','JGP','JHJ','JHT','JJH','JJW','JKK','JKZ'],
        ['2014','HVN','HVZ','HWM','HXB','HXN','HYD','HTY','HZB','HZL','HZZ','JBL','JBY'],
        ['2013','HNT','HPC','HPN','HPY','HRK','HRX','HSK','HSR','HSZ','HTK','HTV','HVF'],
        ['2012','HJC','HJM','HKB','HKL','HKX','HLK','HLW','HMD','HML','HMT','HNC','HNK'],
        ['2011','HBP','HCB','HCR','HDC','HDR','HFF','HFT','HGC','HGM','HGX','HHH','HHT'],
        ['2010','GTC','GTS','GVM','GWC','GWV','GXP','GYD','GYM','GYX','GZJ','GZT','HBG'],
        ['2009','GKS','GLC','GLP','GMC','GMN','GNF','GNY','GPJ','GPW','GRM','GSC','GSR'],
        ['2008','FZR','GBN','GCK','GDH','GFC','GFY','GGV','GHG','GHT','GJJ','GJV','GKH'],
        ['2007','FKY','FLV','FNB','FNZ','FRC','FSJ','FTP','FVJ','FWC','FXB','FXY','FYY'],
        ['2006','DVW','DWT','DXZ','DYY','FBC','FCJ','FDP','FFK','FGF','FHD','FJD','FKC'],
        ['2005','DFZ','DGX','DHZ','DKB','DLD','DMJ','DNP','DPK','DRG','DSC','DTB','DVB'],
        ['2004','CRV','CSS','CTT','CVR','CWR','CXT','CYY','CZP','DBJ','DCH','DDG','DFF'],
        ['2003','CDV','CFM','CGJ','CHF','CJC','CKB','CLD','CLV','CMM','CNK','CPF','CRC'],
        ['2002','BSL','BTF','BTZ','BVW','BWT','BXP','BYP','BZF','BZV','CBP','CCH','CDC'],
        ['2001','BFJ','BGF','BHG','BJC','BKB','BLC','BMF','BMW','BNL','BPG','BRB','BRT'],
        ['2000','---','---','---','---','---','---','---','---','BBJ','BCD','BCY','BDR']
    ];

    $minYear = null;
    $minKey = null;
    $minDiff = strToInt('ZZZ');
    $searchInt = strToInt($searchStr);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($plates); $i++) {
        for ($j = 1; $j < 13; $j++) {
            if(abs($searchInt - strToInt($plates[$i][$j])) < $minDiff) {
                $minDiff = abs($searchInt - strToInt($plates[$i][$j]));
                $minYear = $plates[$i][0];
                $minKey = $plates[$i][$j];
            }
        }
    }

    return [$minYear, $minKey];
}


print_r(find('KHW'));
```

Comment: Thank you @raftx24, looks awesome but unfortunatly I see it is not matching correctly. If I search for print_r(find('GWN')); it returns HLW which is wrong. The closest to GWN is GWV. I wonder why this could be happening?

Comment: I want to give you an idea about the algorithm, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The code down below is by no means optimized, but it's rather a concept of how you might solve your problem.

```
//Flatten out array (one dimension without years and ----)
$flatten = array();
foreach($plates as $platevalues) {
    foreach($platevalues as $pv) {        
        if ($pv != '---' && $pv != '----' && intval($pv) == 0) {
            //Create a string only if valid letters included in the $letters-array
            //This string is then added to the new array that is flattened out
            $pv2 = '';
            for($i=0;$i<strlen($pv);$i++) {
                $letter = substr($pv,$i,1);
                if (in_array($letter, $letters) !== false) {
                    $pv2 .= $letter;
                }
            }
            $flatten[] = $pv2;
        }
    }
}

//Do the search
$search = 'GWN';
$search_result = '';

//Create a new search string based on first found in flattened
//plates array (first G, then GW, then GWN)
for($i=0;$i<strlen($search);$i++) {
    foreach($flatten as $key=>$f) {
        if (substr($search,0,$i+1) == substr($f,0,$i+1)) {
            $search_result .= substr($search,$i,1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
/*
$search_result is: GW
*/

//Create a new array where all items that begins with GW are included
$result = [];
foreach($flatten as $key=>$item) {
    if (substr($search_result,0,strlen($search_result)) == 
    substr($item,0,strlen($search_result))) {
        $result[] = $item;   
    }
}
/*
$result =

array (size=2)
    0 => string 'GWC' (length=3)
    1 => string 'GWV' (length=3)
*/

//Create an array with total ASCII-value for each item 
//in the $result array above
$result_o = [];
foreach($result as $item) {
    $o = 0;
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($item);$i++) {
        $o += ord(substr($item,$i,1));
    }
   $result_o[]= $o;
}
/* 
$result_o = 

array (size=2)
    0 => int 225
    1 => int 244        
*/


//Get the total ASCII-value for the original search string
$search_o = 0;
for($i=0;$i<strlen($search);$i++) {
    $search_o += ord(substr($search,$i,1));
}
/*
$search_ o = 236
*/


//Find closest value in the $result_o (ASCII) - array compared (225,244)
//to the original $search_o ASCII value above (236)
$closest = 0;
$use_key = 0;
foreach($result_o as $key=>$item) {
    if ($closest == 0 || abs($search_o - $closest) > abs($item - $search_o)) {
        $closest = $item;
        $use_key = $key;
    }
}

/* 
$closest = 244 (it's closer to 236 than 225 is)
$use_key = 1
*/
```

To get the result you have:

```
/*
$result =

array (size=2)
    0 => string 'GWC' (length=3)
    1 => string 'GWV' (length=3)
*/

//This should print out GWV
echo 'result=' . $result[$use_key];
```